# If someone finds a good answer, will he able to give awards to the one who answered, expressing his feeling just than up votes?

Tags: support

If someone finds a good answer, he could be able to give awards to the one who answered to express his feeling just than up votes.

Comment: *Why* should you be able to give more than upvotes?

Comment: Nice question..Answer : It is to express feeling which we had when we found some beautiful or easy or intellectual way.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. This is a Q&A site, why do you think expressing your feelings (beyond up voting, which already does that) is something SO *"should"* support.

Comment: What I understood is most people reply or expect only for reputation , up votes etc...Its not all bad but there is some others things which we code for.Had u ever felt happy feeling when u solved some complex issue or something...If not then u wouldnt understand

Comment: Of course I have, but that didn't mean that I wanted to dump pointless comments on SO.

Comment: This ain't Facebook.

Comment: Ok I understood what u said. For example I felt that ur answer is intelluctual for my question then it would be nice to inform u with that feeling using sme tag etc and when it comes to slicing away rep points, all cant do that.

Comment: I just asked what I have in my mind. Forget it.Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: You'll please any expert at SO by not talking to them in txtspeak and marking their post as the answer.

Comment: We don't do fluff here. We don't do "niceties" or introductions, or "thanks"because we only focus on the knowledge being propagated. You'll do old users a bigger favor by asking good questions, upvoting/accepting answers, voting down/close voting bad content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible by awarding a bounty - giving some of your own points to the answerer.

You don't have enough points yet, but as soon as you have 75 or more points, you will be able to place a bounty on a question.
One of the possible reasons for putting a bounty on a question is to reward an especially good answer.